# How to make a bottom input bar in console?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console

**Problem specification:**

-single thread "OUT" writing output to the first n-1 rows of the console

-single thread "IN" reading input from n (most bottom) row of the console

-"OUT" thread should be able to follow "awaiting behavior" meaning it stalls until recieves data and signal to perform output

-"IN" thread should be able to follow "awaiting behavior" as well - no processing should be done unless user types in text and press enter

**Problem description:**

What I am currently looking for is the way to manipulate console so I could achieve desired effect: A bottom row in the console acting as "input bar", independent from "output area". Typing a text should not interfere with output operations and scrolling output area should not displace input bar.
Basically I want to develop funcionality similar to that one implemented in vim.

While I am familiar to WinAPI basics I must admit that I never before tried manipulating console and tbh I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start here: [Consoles (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313033/multithreaded-console-i-o/. In short, this isn't very easy, but it can be done if you're willing to put up with some restrictions.